# Convert video file to TIFF with ffmpeg.dll or avcodec.dll? Is "on-the-fly" possible?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt4, ffmpeg

I want to create a program, which gets a video-file from Qt, converts that video file to TIFF-files and sends them to an algorithm which handles these TIFF-Files.
My questions:

- is it possible with ffmpeg or avcodec not to convert a video-file to TIFF-files first on harddrive and send them to the algorithm after that, but to convert frame for frame and send it to the algorithm right away?
- The more important question: Is it possible to do that not with an external process with ffmpeg.exe, but with ffmpeg.dll? Or is it only possible with avcodec.dll? (It doesn't have to be "on-the-fly" like at my point above) How can I create a ffmpeg.dll with header and lib?

Comment: I'm no master with using words, but I'd change few things here. I'd guess that by *algorithm* you mean a *program* or *script*, by "not saving on hard-drive first" you meant "grabbing it as a variable on your script", which would be lot faster indeed, and finally by "not with an external process" you probably meant including it on your c++ program through a *dll*. So I'd also guess that you've solved all this by now. :)

Answer (score 1):

for exporting tif :
http://www.repaire.net/forums/cinema-numerique/215306-projet-dencodage-dcp.html

Answer (score 0):

Creating a tiff from second 29 in a mpeg, using ffmpeg dd201110 can be done like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 'test.mpg' -vframes 1 -compression_level 0  -ss 29 'test.tiff'
```

YMMV :-D
If you dont want to store the image as a file, take a look at ffmpeg-php

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

> `$movie->getFrame([Integer framenumber])`
>
> Returns a frame from the movie as an ffmpeg_frame object.
>
> `$frame->toGDImage()`
>
> Returns a truecolor GD image of the frame.

There may be C code underneath you can reuse..